# Sending wrong date value in mysql databse

Tags: android

I am trying to send all the value from `edittext` to `database` but all the data are added perfectly in `database` but  `date` field it is showing `0000-00-00` my code is:

```
public class ProposeMeeting1Activity extends Activity
 {   

    TextView txtview,textview,eorg;
    Button bthm,btnsnd;
    String pdate,ptime,pvenue,uid,cdate;         
    HttpPost post;
    HttpResponse res;
    HttpClient client;
    InputStream in;
    StringBuffer sb;
    Date date1;
    String str;
    int ch;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_propose_meeting1);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        pdate = intent.getStringExtra("sdate");
        ptime = intent.getStringExtra("stime");
        pvenue = intent.getStringExtra("svenue");
        uid=intent.getStringExtra("uid");
        bthm= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        eorg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        eorg.setText(uid);
        btnsnd= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnsnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
               public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                try {

                    List<NameValuePair>parameters= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("organiser",eorg.getText().toString()));
                    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attendees",einvite.getText().toString()));
                    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title",etitle.getText().toString()));                
                    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mdate",edate.getText().toString()));
                    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mtime",etime.getText().toString()));
                    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("venue",evenue.getText().toString()));
                    post=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/meetingschedular/sendinvite.php");
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
                    client= new DefaultHttpClient();
                    res=client.execute(post);
                    HttpEntity en=res.getEntity();
                    in=en.getContent();
                    sb=new StringBuffer();
                    while((ch=in.read())!=-1){
                    sb.append((char)ch);
                    }
                    str=sb.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    einvite.setText("");

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

and my php code is as follows:

```
`<?php 

       $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
       mysql_select_db('meetingschedulardata',$con);
       if(!$con)
        {
                  die("can not connect".mysql_error());
         }

       $order="INSERT INTO meetingdetails (organiser,attendees,title,mdate,mtime,venue)     values('$_POST[organiser]','$_POST[attendees]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[mdate]','$_POST[mtime]','$_POST[venue]')";

      $result=mysql_query($order,$con);
      if($result==1)
      {
         echo "Want To Invite More Then Continue";
      }
      else
      {
         echo "Problem occurs while Invitingm".mysql_error();
      }

?>`
```

Comment: How is your database table defined?

Comment: This is my php code
<?php 

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('meetingschedulardata',$con);
if(!$con)
{
die("can not connect".mysql_error());
}


$order="INSERT INTO meetingdetails (organiser,attendees,title,mdate,mtime,venue) values('$_POST[organiser]','$_POST[attendees]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[mdate]','$_POST[mtime]','$_POST[venue]')";

$result=mysql_query($order,$con);

if($result==1)
{
echo "Want To Invite More Then Continue";
}
else{
echo "Problem occurs while Invitingm".mysql_error();
}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I can see is that you're using an EditText for setting a date/time. Although this may not be the root of your problem, it's still a bad idea. EditText is far too flexible and it's hard for you (as a developer) to know what format or how the date/time is being entered into the EditText. A [date/time picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) would be *far* more suitable.

Secondly, how are you storing the date/time in the database? Are you storing it as a string or as [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)? I personally would recommend using the latter since it's easy to store/retrieve and you can format the time in any way you'd like without having to change anything on the database.

But, besides all that, make sure the date/time you are sending is converted into something the date/time column can accept. If the column is defined as a datetime, make sure you're converting the data into an acceptable format.

Comment: i am using mysql and i have declared the field as date.

Comment: The 3rd paragraph of my answer seems to describe your problem exactly. From your PHP code, it does not seem like you are converting the incoming data into an acceptable format for the database. You're just simply taking the incoming data and saving it into the database directly. This would work if the field was simply a text/string...